# Dual booting Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

My primary OS is (and will continue to be) Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  I would like though to also have Windows 10 to allow me to run certain Windows-only software without running it in a virtualized environment.  With this in mind, I have ordered a second NVMe drive to install Windows on.  Does Ubuntu produce documentation to take users through the dual boot configuration process?   Everything I have found online starts with a Windows installation then shows how to add Linux - and I am doing the opposite.  I plan to have each OS on its own drive to prevent "cross contamination".  Am I approaching this correctly?

Comment: Be sure to have both as UEFI (or both as very old BIOS/MBR). Best to unplug or disable Ubuntu drive in UEFI settings & install Windows so it only sees its drive. If both UEFI, then in Ubuntu you can run `sudo update-grub` to add Windows to grub menu for dual booting. Windows fast start up must be off & UEFI Secure Boot must be off. If you want those on, then you can only boot directly from UEFI boot menu.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.  I was planning to temporarily disconnect the Ubuntu drive and install/setup Windows on the new drive.   It was the last part (updating grub) that I was unsure of.  Thanks again.